# How to Change behaviour of ProviderManager in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

The default behaviour of ProviderManager is :

1. Try to authenticate using AuthenticationProviders List, until you get success or you exhaust all AuthenticationProviders.
2. If InternalAuthenticationServiceException is thrown, ProviderManager rethrows this and it doesn't try with more AuthenticationProviders.
3. If AccountStatusException is thrown, ProviderManager rethrows this and it doesn't try with more AuthenticationProviders.

What I want :

1. If InternalAuthenticationServiceException, then It should check if it is allowed to use Other AuthenticationProviders, If yes, then go for it.
2. If AuthenticationException is thrown, that means, user is unauthenticated, than rethrow it and send Unauthenticated response to caller, don't try with more AuthenticationProviders.

What I did :

I made my own ProviderManager (lets call it MyProviderManager) class and wrote my own definition for authenticate(Authentication authentication) method.

Now I want spring to use MyProviderManager instead of ProviderManager.

How should I configure it?
Is there a way?
If not, What are the other approaches through which I can change the behaviour of ProviderManager?

Comment: Should work. How does your security config look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Answer is

1. Define your own Provider bean configuration, either through XML or JAVA.
2. In Http and global-method-security, add authentication-manager-ref as your bean id, and Spring Security will use your Provider Manager instead of Springs'.